# How do I get land permits?

Tags: simcity-social

How do I get land permits in Simcity Social? I am aware of two options:

- Buy with diamonds
- Ask friends

Are there any other ways?

Comment: At a guess, this is how EA intends to convince you to give it money, or to get you to convince other friends to play it so one of them might give them money.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've been able to see so far, both responses above are correct.
However, I would add that certain quests (or maybe random from a building, not sure) seem to grant them as well.
I burned the free one they start you with, then scratched my head how to get more.
I just popped in to see how many diamonds I'd need, and its showing I've got 1 of 2 that I need.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no other way to get land permits other than through friends and diamonds.

Comment: In what way to get the land permits ? I'm Scratching my head to get more land permits but where to get ir thru diamonds and friends.. Please Help, Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Create a Facebook account and then add your original account in SimCity Social. Send yourself Land Permits as a gift - this can be done as much as you want.

Creating a Facebook account is free. You can also do this for other collectables too.